# Проблема многопоточности

Tags: c#, многопоточность, асинхронность

Я перебираю строки в файле в каждой считаю кол-во букв "а", делаю это асинхронно и многопоточно. Почему в многопоточном методе кол-во букв "а" меньше, чем в асинхронном или в просто последовательном. То есть если перебрать строки и подсчитать буквы а, то последовательно будет 65913, асинхронно 65913, а многопоточно будет меньше, например 65909. Может быть какой-то поток мешает завершиться другому потоку? В чём проблема и как её решить?
АСИНХРОННО

```
public static async Task<int> ReadFileAsync(string path)
{
    int count = 0;
    using (StreamReader sr =  File.OpenText(path))
    {
        string line = String.Empty;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = await sr.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                i++;
                MatchCollection matches3 = Regex.Matches(line, "а");
                count += matches3.Count;
                Console.WriteLine($"in line num {i} count symbol a equal: {matches3.Count}");
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

МНОГОПОТОЧНО

```
public static void ReadFileThread(string path)
{
    StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path);
    string line = String.Empty;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(WorkWithLines));
            thread.Start(line);
        }

    }
}
private static void WorkWithLines(object line)
{
    MatchCollection matches3 = Regex.Matches(line.ToString(), "а");
    Console.WriteLine($"in line num count symbol a equal: {matches3.Count}");

    CountForThirdMethod += matches3.Count;
}
```

Comment: Создание потока дорогая операция, потому создавать новый поток для каждой строки - значит наоборот замедлить обработку данных, а не ускорить ее, плюс проблемы с синхронизацией, которую вы поимели. Если хотите многопоточно, то делите общее кол-во строк допустим на 3 части и создавайте под каждую часть отдельный поток, а результаты потом суммируйте.

Answer (score 3):

```
CountForThirdMethod += matches3.Count;
```

`+=` -не атомарная операция. Она разбивается на две

```
var newCountForThirdMethod = CountForThirdMethod + matches3.Count;
CountForThirdMethod = newCountForThirdMethod;
```

При выполнении в несколько потоков может быть наложение вида

```
// CountForThirdMethod == 0
Thread1: var newCountForThirdMethod = CountForThirdMethod + matches3.Count; // 1
Thread2: var newCountForThirdMethod = CountForThirdMethod + matches3.Count; // 1
Thread1: CountForThirdMethod = newCountForThirdMethod; // 1
Thread2: CountForThirdMethod = newCountForThirdMethod; // 1
```

т.е. вроде оба потока сделали `+=`, но один из результатов потерялся. Огораживайте эту строчку `lock`-ом, или используйте [`Interlocked.Add`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.add?view=net-5.0)

Но вообще вам вроде многопоточнось не нужна, скорее всего узким местом все равно будет чтение из файла.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Это задачка просто в целях обучения.

Comment: Рассуждения вроде и правильные, ну судя по статистике, дело не в этом и операции похоже всё же атомарные, хотя это и не было гарантировано. :)  Если бы была проблема с атомарностью, думаю, статистика была бы гораздо хуже.

Comment: У меня вот кст ещё вопрос, я совсем в этом новичок, что конкретно нужно ограничивать lock'ом, только строчку CountForThirdMethod += matches3.Count; Или что-то ещё?

Comment: @АлексейМелентьев Ещё надо ограждать локом то место, где вы читаете переменную `CountForThirdMethod`. Кстати, хорошо бы вы показали то место в программе, где вы это делаете.

Comment: вот объявляю         public static int CountForThirdMethod { get; set; } = 0;  дальше присваиваю значение             CountForThirdMethod += matches3.Count;   И вот потом в Мейне             stopwatch3.Start();
            ReadFileThread(path);
            int count3 = CountForThirdMethod;
            stopwatch3.Stop();

Comment: @АлексейМелентьев достаточно огородить те места, где вы меняете эту переменную на основе старого ее значения (т.е. только одну в вашем примере). Чтение ограничивать не надо. Ну и еще да, надо ждать потоков (как в соседнем ответе написано).

Comment: `Чтение ограничивать не надо`, чтобы не было недопонимания, важно заметить, что если читаете, чтобы на базе этого прочитанного значения потом посчитать и записать, но блокировать нужно перед этой самой операцией чтения.

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(WorkWithLines));
thread.Start(line);
```

Это, конечно, прекрасно, но ваша программа может завершиться раньше, чем завершатся все запущенные таким образом потоки. Правильный шаблон работы с потоками - вы должны собрать собранные потоки в список, а потом сделать для всех запущенных потоков присоединение к основному потоку после их окончания:

```
thread.Join()
```

Скорее всего в вашем случае почти все потоки успевают завершиться успешно, кроме нескольких самых последних, судя по статистике. Вернее, вы успеваете где-то напечатать значение переменной `CountForThirdMethod` раньше, чем завершился последний поток (или несколько последних потоков).

Ну то есть примерно так:

```
var threads = new List<Thread>();
while ...
{
    ...
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(WorkWithLines));
    thread.Start(line);
    threads.Append(thread);
    ...
}

foreach thread in threads
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

Comment: да, похоже вы правы, in line num count symbol a equal: 1
in line num count symbol a equal: 0
in line num count symbol a equal: 6
in line num count symbol a equal: 4
in line num count symbol a equal: 0
Wasted the time consistently method 00:00:01.4446772

Wasted the time async method 00:00:01.3967833

Wasted the time multy Thread method 00:00:13.9505353

Total count of "a" in consistently method: 65913

Total count of "a" in async method: 65913

Total count of "a" in multy Thread method: 65910

in line num count symbol a equal: 3
in line num count symbol a equal: 0

Comment: Это вывод с консоли, а что-то можете посоветовать?

Comment: @АлексейМелентьев Хоть я и не привёл полностью код, но, я думаю, вы сами справитесь. Как я и написал в ответе - сделайте список, собирайте в него все `thread` которые запускаете, а после окончания цикла пройдите по этому списку и сделайте для каждого `thread.Join()`. Но вообще лучше всё-таки не дробить так мелко работу, как правильно написали в комментарии к вопросу. Да и вообще лучше использовать асинхронность и `Task`-и и не мучиться с этим всем. Но понимать как это работает надо.

Comment: Даа, согласен, спасибо. Просто это стажёрская задачка, мне её дали, написать и асинхронно и многопоточно, поэтому придётся всё делать. Спасибо большое за ответы, пойду разбираться с join))

Comment: @АлексейМелентьев Добавил в ответ примерно как код будет выглядеть :)